# Does a Raspberry Pi have enough CPU power to run a full node and an electrs server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, raspberry-pi, performance, electrum-server

Very curious if anyone has this particular setup, currently am running the aforementioned on an old Acer laptop but it's struggling hard.

Comment: Which rPI? There are several versions.